# Kitchen test not running

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, test-kitchen

I was trying to run `kitchen list` and it was showing gem conflict between `mixlib-shellout v2.1.0 and v2.2.6`. Until yesterday everything was running fine and i have no idea from where this conflict arises.

This is the error i was getting

```
I, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.707167 #5551]  INFO -- Kitchen: -----> Starting Kitchen (v1.4.2)
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.722778 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: ------Exception-------
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.722842 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: Class: Kitchen::ClientError
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.722870 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: Message: Could not load the 'vagrant' driver from the load path. Please ensure that your driver is installed as a gem or included in your Gemfile if using Bundler.
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.722893 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: ---Nested Exception---
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.722914 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: Class: Gem::ConflictError
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.722935 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: Message: Unable to activate mixlib-install-1.0.2, because mixlib-shellout-2.1.0 conflicts with mixlib-shellout (>= 2.2.6)
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.722955 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: ------Backtrace-------
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.722975 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:50:in `rescue in for_plugin'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.722996 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/driver.rb:40:in `for_plugin'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723015 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/config.rb:226:in `new_driver'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723035 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/config.rb:239:in `new_instance'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723056 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/config.rb:135:in `block in build_instances'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723104 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/config.rb:134:in `map'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723124 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/config.rb:134:in `with_index'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723143 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/config.rb:134:in `build_instances'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723162 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/config.rb:110:in `instances'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723181 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/command.rb:115:in `filtered_instances'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723200 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/command.rb:145:in `parse_subcommand'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723219 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/command/test.rb:43:in `block in call'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723238 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723257 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/command/test.rb:41:in `call'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723276 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:56:in `perform'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723295 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:217:in `test'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723314 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723333 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723352 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/cli.rb:308:in `invoke_task'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723371 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723391 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723427 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/bin/kitchen:13:in `block in <top (required)>'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723447 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/lib/kitchen/errors.rb:154:in `with_friendly_errors'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723477 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/embedded/apps/test-kitchen/bin/kitchen:13:in `<top (required)>'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723498 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/bin/kitchen:15:in `load'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723517 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: /opt/chefdk/bin/kitchen:15:in `<main>'
E, [2016-04-06T23:01:16.723536 #5551] ERROR -- Kitchen: ----------------------
```

To remove gem conflict i remove mixlib-shellout v 2.1.0 which turn out be a mistake. Now on running kitchen list i am getting this

```
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'mixlib-shellout' (= 2.1.0) - did find: [mixlib-shellout-2.2.6] (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/shivams/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0:/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:58:in `gem'
    from /opt/chefdk/bin/kitchen:4:in `<main>'
```

I am totally blank at present and have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just want to implode your ChefDK install (and clear `~/.chefdk/gems`) and re-install. Sounds like you might have mixed versions of things.